# If $f$ is continuous and $X$ is locally compact, then $f(X)$ is locally compact.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, examples-counterexamples

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, $X$ locally compact and $f:X\to Y$ a function. Prove or disprove:
>
> a) If $f$ is continuous, then $f(X)$ is locally compact.
>
> b) If $f$ is continuous and open, then $f(X)$ is locally compact.

I proved b), therefore a) must be false.

So a counterexample is needed to show a) is false.

What could be the counterexample?

Please any help or suggestion.

Comment: First step: identify a space that is not locally compact.

Comment: You are correct that $(a)$ is false. Do you know any spaces that are not locally compact?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yes I know only one $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @bella good start. Can you think of a continuous function from $f$ from a locally compact space with $f(X) = \mathbb Q$? Don't instantly respond in the negative. Think about it for a while.

Comment: Impressive. @Umberto must be a wonderful teacher.

Comment: @UmbertoP. :( I don't know

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Try to think of a discrete space and a non-locally compact space. Note that any function from a discrete space is continuous (why?), hence you can construct a function from the discrete space to the non-locally compact space and it will be a counterexample.

**Edit:** A simple, well-known discrete space is $\Bbb N\subseteq \Bbb R$ with the usual topology. Hence, if we let $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$, we can define $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$ by $f(n)=q_n$, in which case we have a continuous function from a locally compact space to a non-locally compact space.

Comment: May I know why didn't you tell me that you edited the question 2 days later? that would have helped me a lot days ago..

Comment: We could also have $f: \mathbb{Z_+} \times \mathbb{Z_+} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ by $f(p,q) = p/q$.